# Why i cant see submit button; checkbox and div on IE

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer

I have [this landing page](http://ari.seveloff.com/dbp/), for some reason I can't see the check box, submit button and a div that are in the code. Everything works in chrome and Firefox. I understand that IE dosen't always get media queries so I made [this landing page](http://ari.seveloff.com/dbp/ex/) that calls a diferent css file when it detects IE, but it made no difference.

I have a few questions:
1. What is causing this? 
2. How can I fix it? Is there a file, like modernizer, that I can load to modify code for IE.
3. I am also using [this js addon](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/jquery-placeholder) on the second link with a separate css file, in order to see place holders in IE. This also doesn't work, if someone could tell me why, that would be great

Answer (score 2):

I see the checkbox just fine in IE.  why don't you show an image of what you are seeing.  Also, clear your browser cache.

To help debug, you should press F12, then click on console.  make sure there are no errors.   Then click Network.  Make sure all css/javascript is loaded with no errors.  finally, in the dom explorer, click the arrow, and click on the page and see if the elements are there.

Comment: I think that what you see as a picture of the check box. which i.e version you are using?

Comment: @DavSev I tried in ie 8,9,10,11, and edge.  I see the checkmark and it checks.

Comment: is the checkbox clickable in all of these?

Comment: @DavSev yes,  ie 8 doesn't show any css, but the checkmark is there. all others look fine.

Comment: ok. what you saw was the background image elemnts. now i have cleaned the background image. it is easier to see the problem. this is the link http://ari.seveloff.com/dbp/ex/     pleade check in IE 9. how can it be fixed? i dont find why i can not controll the problematic elemts

Answer (score 0):

as i see it this is the solution to my question

at the top of the css file i had this row:

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/earlyaccess/opensanshebrew.css);
```

once i removed it i got the mossing elemnts.

tnx for helping

Dav